# ADF Mobile: Invoke AMX Page to display on user screen using JavaScript

Tags: oracle-adf, oracle-adf-mobile

My question is very simple.

In ADF Mobile, I have HTML page and there is a button on it. I want to run JavaScript code on button click and navigate to AMX Page. How I can achieve this functionality.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In button properties in AMX page click `action listener` and create Bean and Method

Add below code in order to execute zoomIn JS Function

```
AdfmfContainerUtilities.invokeContainerJavaScriptFunction("com.mohamed.ios.feature1",
                                                             "zoomIn",
                                                              new Object[] { });
```

- First Parameter: Feature Id
- Second Parameter: Javascript Function
- Name Third Parameter: Java Script Function Parameters

If it's HTML page once you choose a button in `property inspector` under javascript you will find all the javascript events you can use( if `property inspector` not visible click `View -> Property Inspector`).

you can add the JS function in the `OnClick` event then in that JS function you can use below code to go to the feature that has your AMX page.

```
adf.mf.api.gotoFeature("feature0",
          function(req, res) { alert("gotoFeature complete"); },
function(req, res) { alert("gotoFeature failed with " +
                            adf.mf.util.stringify(res); }
   );
```

Make sure you include the JS file in feature under content tab.

And in order to navigate to AMX page from a button on another AMX page pass the flowCase to below method

```
public void doNavigation(String flowCase) {

    AdfmfContainerUtilities.invokeContainerJavaScriptFunction(AdfmfJavaUtilities.getFeatureName(),
                                                              "adf.mf.api.amx.doNavigation",
                                                              new Object[] { flowCase });
}
```

The doNavigation method is calling a standard ADFM JS API called `adf.mf.api.amx.doNavigation` and it passes the flowCase name to it.

Comment: Page is designed in HTML page, where I can find the properties of button?

Comment: check the last update i added brief on how to go to amx page from HTML page, for more info check out this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/doc.111240/e24475/phgapfeatures.htm

Comment: how to navigate form AXM to html kindly help me